# How can I hide the price of a product in Bigcartel?

Tags: html, css, hide, product, bigcartel

I have a bigcartel site selling my products however some products I just want displayed as 'portfolio' pieces without a price (and possibly without 'sold out' or 'coming soon' etc). 
Is there a way to hide the price for those products?
Could I categorize the products and make every product in a certain category have a different code?

I'm using the 'Luna' theme.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have access to the code? I'd right click on that price, and inspect the element in developer tools. Then find that element in the CSS and hide it by using `display: none`. Or find it in the theme file and delete it.

Comment: I have access but its a 'skeletal' format specifically for bigcartels templates. I can delete the line `<h3>{{ product.default_price | money_with_sign }}</h3>` but it deletes it for all. I only want to do it to certain ones, but dont have that option.

Comment: I've worked with big cartel before, so am familiar with the templating scheme. It's probably running from a loop though, so either you hide none or you hide all. Only other thing I can think of is to create a new category like you mentioned called "coming soon", and apply a new template to those items that don't display price. Other than that, look into possibilities of conditionals in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a ton of conditional statements to check against product names, you may just want to have your portfolio products added to a "Portfolio" category and only hide the price for products in that category.

Add this to the top of Customize Design > Advanced > Product:

```
{% for category in product.categories %}
  {% if category.name == 'Portfolio' %}
    {% assign hide_price = 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Next, change the line that displays the price to this:

```
{% if hide_price != 1 %}<h3>{{ product.default_price | money_with_sign }}</h3>{% endif %}
```

You could also use the same conditional statement above to hide the product status - like sold out, coming soon, etc.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution, but didnt seem to work. 

I gave the product a 'Portfolio' category,
I included those lines at the very top of 'products' html, and changed that single line and it saves it all properly but doesnt seem to change anything. 

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add it into the individual Product page, or the Products page? This code is for the single Product page, if you want to hide it on the Products thumbnail page then you have to put the for loop in a different spot.